# Creating Generic Method to Create Controls in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, controls, custom-controls

I am trying to generate a method on a custom control that will take an object I have created with metadata pertaining to the control and have the control created in this one method and added to the page control collection. Below is the object that I created to contain the control metadata.

```
public class ListControlSetup
{
    public ListControl ListControl { get; set; }
    public String ControlId { get; set; }
    public String ControlCssClass { get; set; }
    public bool CausesValidation { get; set; }
    public IuIDropDownDictionary DropDownDictionary { get; set; }
    public String DropDownMethod { get; set; }
    public bool AutoPostback { get; set; }                      
}
```

I then have a method that takes the above object as a parameter and creates the control. Lets say a dropdownlist in this instance. Lets say I wanted to pass an Event for the dropdownlist OnSelectedIndexchange event. How would I do this in a generic fashion so that I could have the event wired up in the called procedure. Below is the called procedure I currently have.

```
    private void ControlSetUp(ListControlSetup control)
    {
        control.ListControl = this.CreateDropDownListControl(control.ControlId, control.ControlCssClass, control.CausesValidation);
        _myManager.DropDownMethod = control.DropDownMethod;
        _myManager.FillDropDown(control.DropDownDictionary, control.ListControl);                       
        this.Controls.Add(control.ListControl);
    }
```

below is the call and object instantiation.

```
        ListControlSetup lcs = new ListControlSetup{ ListControl = ddlControl, DropDownMethod = SPConsts.GetData, 
                            DropDownDictionary = new DataDictionary(), ControlId="ddlControlId", ControlCssClass="inputfield", CausesValidation=false, AutoPostback=false};
        ControlSetUp(lcs);
```

Any advice would be great as to how I would add events to the ControlSetUp method.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your problem is with delegates. The `DropDownList.OnSelectedIndexChanged` event is declared using a delegate of type `EventHandler` (which itself is declared in System.dll). So add a method of the same `EventHandler` type to your `ListControlSetup` class, like this:

```
public class ListControlSetup
{
    ...
    EventHandler OnSelectedIndexChanged;  
    // Don't let the stackoverflow coloring fool you, 
    // 'OnSelectedIndexChanged' is a member variable name.
}
```

Then, in your `ControlSetUp()` method, do this:

```
if ( control.OnSelectedIndexChanged != null )
    ddlControl.SelectedIndexChanged += control.OnSelectedIndexChanged;
```

Finally, to assign the ListControlSetup's OnSelectedIndexChanged list member, do this:

```
ListControlSetup lcs = new ListControlSetup() { ... };
lcs.OnSelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler( ddl_SelectedIndexChanged );
```

That assumes your event handler method is ddl_SelectedIndexChanged, of course.

Hope this helps!